# htaccess - displaying 500 Error even enabling the htaccess file in httpd.conf on localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess displaying 500 server error.
Location of file is root folder.
Below is the code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .signup.php [L]
RewriteRule .* .signup.php [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've enabled htaccess file in httpd.conf file 
that is

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Satisfy all
</Directory>
```

and

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteBase` line is faulty without specifying a directory.
Try either: `RewriteBase /`  -or- removing the line entirely.
If that doesn't work, I think it would be safer to write your .htaccess file like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase / 

#If we're already on .signup.php, exit so we don't get stuck in a loop
    RewriteRule .signup.php - [L]

#If doesn't exist
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#rewrite to .signup.php and read from the top of .htaccess again
    RewriteRule .* .signup.php [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

That way we avoid redirection loops in case the .signup.php file doesn't exist either..
If that still doesn't work, try testing without the PT flag, it has a tendency of complicating .htaccess if you're not absolutely sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: A "dot file" (ie. `.signup.php`) also looks strange as a publicly accessible file? Most servers will actively block access to this, which could also cause a 500 error. (?)